# Extracting a particular part of Kafka Topic Msg in Python

Tags: python, apache-kafka

I am trying to extract the **VALUE** part from a bunch pf Kafka Topic Msg's in Python.
I am trying to subscribe to a Kafka Topic and read the Latest Message and parse it.
While trying to split the below Kafka Topic Msg by '=',i get the below error -

```
AttributeError: 'ConsumerRecord' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Also the object type of the below string is -

```
<class 'kafka.consumer.fetcher.ConsumerRecord'>
```

Sample Kafka Topic Msg -

> ConsumerRecord(topic=u'xxxxxxxx', partition=0, offset=55,
>   timestamp=XXXXXXXXXX, timestamp_type=0, key=None,
>   **value='{"snapshot":[{"active":"XXXXXXXXXX","buffers":"0","cached":"XXXXXXXXXX","inactive":"313581568","memory_free":"XXXXXXXXXX","memory_total":"XXXXXXXXXX","swap_cached":"0","swap_free":"0","swap_total":"0"}],"action":"snapshot","name":"memory_info","hostIdentifier":"XXXXXXXXXX","calendarTime":"Wed
>   Sep  6 18:54:48 2017 UTC","unixTime":"XXXXXXXXXX","epoch":"0"}'**,
>   checksum=-XXXXXXXXXX, serialized_key_size=-1,
>   serialized_value_size=375)

Could someone please guide as to what's the best way to extract the Highlighted (bold) part of the Kafka Topic Msg.

Comment: There is no split() attribute for an object. As per Kafka docs, have you tried to read attributes using ConsumerRecord('above_data').value ?

Comment: Let me try that.

Comment: that worked, thanks a lot Anil_M

Answer (score 0):

**Solved!**

Just use **`value`** attribute of that record.

For example, the following is my Kafka Consumer code.

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer

consumer = KafkaConsumer(
    bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092',
    auto_offset_reset='latest',
    group_id='test'
    )

consumer.subscribe('test')

for msg in consumer:
    print(msg.value.decode('UTF-8'))
```

In the above code, we have written **`msg.value`** in the lastline, which gives the value of the data we want to extract from that ConsumerRecord of Kafka.